# How to check if a BigInteger is null

Tags: java, biginteger, compareto

I have a code which may assign null to a BigInteger. I need to check if it is null or not.

I've tried the following things, and they do not work:

1. `==` will just check the reference, not the value.

   ```
   BigInteger x = BigInteger.ONE;

   if(x== null)
   {
       System.out.println( x );
   }
   ```

Output of above is it prints x. (Somehow the boolean condition is satisfied, even though x is not null).

2. Following gives NullPointerException upon comparing

   ```
   BigInteger x = BigInteger.ONE;
   BigInteger myNull = null;

   if(x.compareTo(myNull) == 0 )
   {
       System.out.println( x );
   }
   ```
3. Another NPE:

   ```
   BigInteger x = BigInteger.ONE;

   if(x.compareTo(null) == 0)
   {
       System.out.println( x );
   }
   ```

How do I check if a BigInteger is null properly?

Comment: Do you want to know whether the object is a `null` reference, or whether it has the value zero, or both?

Comment: It's hard to believe that `1)` prints `x`. to check against null `if(x== null)` should be fine, otherwise you are conparing to something else  (local variables hide member variables, use `this.` to be clear on what you are comparing)

Comment: `.toString()`.equals("")

Comment: I just ran your first block of code and it does NOT print x.  Better check your output.

Answer (score 6):

There is a difference between a `null` reference and an object with the value 0. To check for `null` references, use:

```
BigInteger value = getValue();
if (value != null) {
  // do something
}
```

To check for the value 0, use:

```
BigInteger value = getValue();
if (!BigInteger.ZERO.equals(value)) {
  // do something
}
```

To ensure the object is neither a `null` reference nor has the value 0, combine both:

```
BigInteger value = getValue();
if (value != null && !value.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
  // do something
}
```

---

*2015-06-26: Edited according to @Arpit's comment.*

Comment: To check for the value 0, you can also use `value.signum() == 0`.

Comment: I think `if(!(BigInteger.ZERO).equals(value)){
   // do something
  }` will be more safe, if value is null.

Answer (score 2):

`.compareTo(arg)` throws a NullPointerException if `arg` is `null`.

You should check if `arg` is `null` prior to calling the method.